# Are $(\mathbb{R} - 0, \times)$ and $(\mathbb{R}, +)$ the same group? What is its name?

Tags: group-theory

I'm trying to justify to a friend why it's "not a coincidence" that $a^ba^c = a^{b+c}$, and I want to argue that it's because the structure of $\mathbb{R}$ under addition is exactly the same as the structure of $\mathbb{R} - \{0\}$ under multiplication.

Is "group" the right term to use here? It seems like that to me, since we have closure, inverses, associativity, and an identity. But does a more specific term apply? Am I indeed correct that the groups are the same? Is there a name for this group, and/or examples of it in other contexts?

Comment: Group is the right term (in fact you could even say "Lie group"). They are not the same group unless you restrict to the positive reals in the multiplicative version. The group on the left could be called $\text{GL}_1(\mathbb{R})^{+}$ and the group on the right is just called $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: But the statement that these two groups are isomorphic is more or less just a restatement of the claim that $a^b a^c = a^{b+c}$; it's not an explanation of why this is true.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan One could argue it's "not a coincidence" because $GL_1(\mathbb{R})^+$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are both connected and simply connected $1$-dimensional Lie groups, of which there is only one, up to isomorphism.

Comment: @aes: that is, in turn, just a restatement of the claim, not an explanation of it. It relies on facts which are at least as complicated as the fact that $a^b a^c = a^{b+c}$. Here is a more precise version of what I think needs explaining: if $k$ is an arbitrary field (say a finite field), then in general there is no interesting map from the additive group of $k$ to the multiplicative group. What makes $k = \mathbb{R}$ special among fields?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Real analysis (or differential geometry, if you prefer) results, I suppose. The reals are of course quite special, as the unique complete ordered field. I'm not trying to make too much of this, which is certainly rather more complicated than exponentiation (hence the "one could argue").

Comment: What you noticed is the key motivation for the invention of logarithms by John Napier, although his development was tortuous in hindsight.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The groups are not the same: $-1\times -1 = 1$ and $1$ is the identity of $(\mathbb{R}-\{0\},\times)$ but there's no $a\neq 0 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $a+a = 0$, which is the identity of $(\mathbb{R},+)$.

However, let $\mathbb{R}_+$ denote the positive reals.

Then $(\mathbb{R}_+,\times)$ is isomorphic (as group) to $(\mathbb{R},+)$.

To give an isomorphism, use the exponential map $\operatorname{Exp}: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_+$, which is a bijection and a homomorphism because $e^{a+b} = e^a \times e^b$, as you mention.

Comment: If I restrict to the positive reals, what is the name of the group that is $(\mathbb{R}_+, \times)$ and $(\mathbb{R}, +)$? Is there one?

Comment: "The multiplicative group of positive reals" and "the additive group of the real numbers" would do. For more symbol-based names, Qiaochu has given reasonable ones in the comments.

Comment: If they're isomorphic groups, is there not just one name I can use for both of them? Something like -- I'm reaching into stuff I don't really understand here -- "the cyclic group" or "the symmetric group"?

Comment: There are many "coincidences" in which low-dimensional Lie groups have multiple names. You can see this with small finite groups too: the symmetric group on $2$ letters is the same as the cyclic group of order $2$. The symmetric group on $3$ letters is the same as the dihedral group of order $6$.

Comment: I think it would simple be called the real additive group, since that is the basic case, and there will be lots of embeddings of the group into other groups. @EliRose

Answer (score 4):

No:

$-1$ has order $2$ in $(\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}, \times)$.  Are there any elements of order $2$ in $(\mathbb{R}, +)$?  Remember that an isomorphism of groups preserves the orders of the elements.

To answer your other question, "group" is indeed the correct term to use.

As an aside, even though the group structure between these is different, there *is* a bijection from one to the other.

Comment: I don't actually know any group theory. What is meant by 'order' in this context?

Comment: @EliRose, the order of an element $x$ in a group is the smallest natural number $n$ such that $x^n = e$, where $e$ is the identity element.  If no such natural number exists, then we say the order of $x$ is infinite.